# Java use of Scanner with System.in

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I have an instance of `Scanner` application-wide defined as `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)`. When I call `scanner.nextLine()`, will it block if no line is found and wait for user input?

Strangely, if I run my code via IntelliJ, it will work properly and wait for user to input a line. However, when run in terminal, it will just throw `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found` on first call of `scanner.nextLine()`. What happened and how I can tune it?

### A minimum sample

```java
public class ScannerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Input: ");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Output: " + input);
    }
}
```

[Run via IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zW63.gif)

[Run via Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPg2a.gif)

Comment: I'm not aware of an issue why your code should behave differently in your IDE and your terminal. Can you provide the code in question in the form of an [mre].

Comment: I concur can you post the relevant code that behaves flaky?

Comment: have you tried to close the scanner after use ? it may cause similar issues

Comment: @KASMIG. Nope, I just tried :(

Comment: @KASMIG. No, a `Scanner` wrapping `System.in` should not be closed, as this would close the underlying stream aswell.

Comment: @maloomeister Yep, this is the answer. Thank you so much!